# Locating IP v4 packets in binary data from stdin

Tags: python, binary, ip, stdin

I would like to be able to read data from stdin and scan the data for 0x45 which is the start of my IP header. But I can't seem to get my head around how I could identify the start of the IP header! My attempt is as follows, and i belive the problem is in how I read the data and that either the binary data needs to be converted or my value to check for needs an convertion:

```
while True:
    for data in sys.stdin.read():
        if(data==0x45):
            #do somethin with the data...
```

Comment: Can you post an example your input data (from stdin), please?

Comment: Here is a xxd dump of a snippet from the binary stream: "...080045b952ddacee...." Where I would like to locate the 0x45

Comment: `0x45` is the  character `E`, you might get a ton of false positives.

Comment: I know, this is just the start of the program the rest will be checking the entire IP header...When I can figure out how to identify the start :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are comparing hex with decimal. You are looking for `45` I think and compare with `0x45`.

```
>> print(0x45)
69
```

So to find the correct part you should compare with something like this

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    if "45" in line:
        # do something with found data in line
```

Comment: That would be because XXD converts the data from binary to HEX in order to make it "readable". The data is originally binary and therefor in order for your solution to work I would need to convert it to HEX by f.ex. piping it through XXD first which is undesirable...